# React JS throw "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error when i want to access object details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to show my users details in modal when I click on my users list.
I pass the user ID as props to modal and in modal I find the user by javascript find() method and user_id.
this method returns my requested user as an Object and I can show it by console.log() but when I want to access to object properties for example "user.name" or "user.email" react thrown an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
//users.js code part

{ showUserDetails ? <div className="ModalContainer" >
       <div className="userModal">
           <div className="modalBody">
               <span className="close">X</span>
               <SelectedUser selectedUserId={selectedUserId}/>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div> : <div></div>
}
```

```
// SelectedUser.js codes

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const SelectedUser = ({selectedUserId, users}) => {
    let user = users.find(user=> user.id === selectedUserId)
    console.log(user.name)
    return ( 
       <React.Fragment>
            <p><b>Name:</b> {user.name}</p>
            <p><b>User Name:</b> {user.username}</p>
            <p><b>Email:</b> {user.email}</p>
            <p>
                <b>Address:</b> 
                {`  ${user.address.suite}, ${user.address.street}, ${user.address.city}
                [zip Code: ${user.address.zipcode}]
                `}
            </p>
            <p><b>Phone: </b>{user.phone}</p>
            <p><b>WebSite: </b>{user.website}</p>
            <p><b>Company: </b>{user.company.name}</p>
       </React.Fragment>
     );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    users: Object.values(state.users.users)
})


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(SelectedUser));
```

Comment: Is the `SelectedUser` component being rendered before the redux store is filled?

Comment: @Saeid! Just wrote you an answer, let me know if its helpful to you. :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo , sorry Chris, i had a trouble in last days...

Comment: @SaeidBarzegar whatsup friend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SelectedUser component you should check if the users-state is available before rendering.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const SelectedUser = ({selectedUserId, users}) => {
    let user;
    let content;
    if(users && users.length > 0){
        user = users.find(user=> user.id === selectedUserId);
    } else {
        return <div>Loading....</div>
    }

    if(Object.keys(user).length >= 0){
       content = (<React.Fragment>
            <p><b>Name:</b> {user.name}</p>
            <p><b>User Name:</b> {user.username}</p>
            <p><b>Email:</b> {user.email}</p>
            <p>
                <b>Address:</b> 
                {`  ${user.address.suite}, ${user.address.street}, ${user.address.city}
                [zip Code: ${user.address.zipcode}]
                `}
            </p>
            <p><b>Phone: </b>{user.phone}</p>
            <p><b>WebSite: </b>{user.website}</p>
            <p><b>Company: </b>{user.company.name}</p>
       </React.Fragment>)
   } else {
       content = "Loading"
   }
   return(
      <div>{content}</div>
   )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    users: Object.values(state.users.users)
})


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(SelectedUser));
```

Comment: I test your solution...
but it, not works...

the main problem is that the component can find the user
I can see it in console
the finded user info type is object ( typeOf())....
but when I want to see the properties app return null!!!

Comment: awesome! no worries, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: do you think the problem is the find() method output?

Comment: Oh yeah definitely, I dont know what happened to my solution haha. Let me update it for you.

Comment: @SaeidBarzegar alright try that out and let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: thanks, man ... that's worked...
but I confused... the data called from vuex
why it have a delay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193134/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-saeid-barzegar).

Comment: @SaeidBarzegar 
It could be a combination of things
Sometimes when you pass props to one component or another, it will take time for that data to travel down the flow. But your component will try to render itself anyway, even if it doesnt have all the data yet
Also, if you're trying to grab data from an API, it follows the same principle, it takes time for data to get through, so its good to setup your logic to account for that time of scenario.